# Django create_or_update model attribute command works fine but update fails

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to write a CSV helper that reads the CSV file and updates or creates fields in the model. The create_or_update query is working fine, but it is only creating not updating. On changing the create_or_update to update it throws an error. The code of the CSV helper is :

```
def insert_books_from_dictionary(data):

    category, created = Category.objects.update_or_create(name=data['category'])
    sub_category = None

    if data['sub_category'].decode('utf-8') != '':
        sub_category, created = SubCategory.objects.update_or_create(name=data['sub_category'], category=category)

    publisher, created = Publisher.objects.update_or_create(name=data['publishers'])
    # convert strings to float

    # ToDo : Fix constraints and create a function
    # to handle data check and conversion
    try:
        price = float(data['mrp_price'])
    except ValueError:
        price = 0.0
        pass

    try:
        pages = float(data['pages'])
    except ValueError:
        pages = None
        pass
    isbn_13_str = str(data['isbn_13'])
    isbn_10_str = str(data['isbn_10'])
    image_url_str = str(data['image_url'])
    binding = 1 if data['binding'] == 'Hardboard' else 2
    book, created = Book.objects.update(title=data['title'],description=data['description'], pages=pages, binding=binding, price=price, category=category,sub_category=sub_category, edition_and_year=data['edition_and_year'],
        isbn_10=isbn_10_str, isbn_13=isbn_13_str,image_url=image_url_str)

    book.publishers.add(publisher)

    authors = re.split(",", data['authors'].decode('utf-8'))
    for author in authors:
        author, created = Author.objects.update_or_create(name=author.strip())

        book.authors.add(author)

    return dict(book_id=book.id)
```

It throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "common/util/upload.py", line 18, in <module>
uploadbooks = book_upload(old_file, newfile)
File "common/util/upload.py", line 12, in book_upload
insert_seller_books_from_dictionary(req_data)
File "/home/subhajit/textnook/common/util/csv_helper.py", line 132, in    insert_seller_books_from_dictionary
book_id = insert_books_from_dictionary(data)
File "/home/subhajit/textnook/common/util/csv_helper.py", line 167, in insert_books_from_dictionary
isbn_10=isbn_10_str, isbn_13=isbn_13_str,image_url=image_url_str)
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

On changing update to create the error is no more. How do i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
book, created = Book.objects.update(title=data['title'],description=data['description'], pages=pages, binding=binding, price=price, category=category,sub_category=sub_category, edition_and_year=data['edition_and_year'],
            isbn_10=isbn_10_str, isbn_13=isbn_13_str,image_url=image_url_str)
```

you are using `update`, not `update_or_create`

`Book.objects.update` updates only and [returns the number of rows affected](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update), which is the `'long' object is not iterable` python complains about, since it has to assign its elements to the tuple `book, created`

Comment: When I am using update_or_create it is creating instead of updating. For example I upload the same book details with only a change in price, it creates a new entry instead of updating it.

Comment: I ignore what you intend to do in your code. As said, `Book.objects.update` returns a number, not a tuple. See my updated answer

Comment: So if I only want to update and not create how should I proceed?

Comment: I presume you can either do `numrows = Book.objects.update(title=...` or `book, created = Book.objects.update_or_create(...`, depending on what you need to do

Comment: This is what i tried at the very beginning but all it does is creates a new entry:
    `book, created = Book.objects.update_or_create(title=data['title'],description=data['description'], pages=pages, binding=binding, price=price, category=category,sub_category=sub_category, edition_and_year=data['edition_and_year'],
        isbn_10=data['isbn_10'], isbn_13=data['isbn_13'],image_url=data['image_url'])`